# Ursina : change FirstPersonController controls

Tags: python, python-3.x, game-engine

I'm trying to make a 3D game in Ursina. I managed to have a working FirstPersonController, but it is using WASD. I'm french, and thus have an AZERTY keyboard, which isn't really convenient... Do you know how I could change my controls to move the FirstPersonController ?

I'd also like to be able to use "special" buttons of my mouse. For exemple, the "forward" and "backward" ones, to sprint and jump !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The WSAD keys for movement are hard-coded in the FirstPersonController class' `update()` method. Overwriting that (by extending the class) didn't work for me so the easiest way would be running your own version of Ursina. That is, don't install it through pip but clone the Git repo, edit the code and install it via `python setup.py`, as described in the documentation.

If you feel that this would be a useful feature, you could add an [issue on Github](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues).

Comment: Yes I thought about that, like, directly writing this in the library file, but I was wondering if there was any way to do this within the library... So there is not ^^'
Thanks (again xD)

Answer (score 3):

You can either copy the code, which you're probably going to do if you need custom movement anyway, or you can rebind the keys with `input_handler.rebind(to_key, from_key)`

Comment: Thanks, but I found a way to do it using the heksecraft sample (or something) from ursina, that worked using self.direction

Answer (score 0):

For changing keys you need to scroll up and when you see"ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController" then
you do ctrl + click on "first_person_controller". Next, you scroll down until you get to the line 44-45 and you change .If it doesn't work use visual studio code.