# Can I move Ursina FirstPersonController by scrolling mouse wheel?

Tags: python, mousewheel, ursina

I would like to move forward and backward by scrolling mouse wheel.

How can I adjust `ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller.FirstPersonController` so that it is controlled by mouse only... specifically, I'd like the forward and backward movements to be controlled by scrolling with **the mouse wheel**.

Would you be so kind and advise me on **how can I read the mouse scroll delta?**

---

Firstly I have looked up the [Ursina Engine documentation](https://www.ursinaengine.org/entity_basics.html#Mouse%20Input)... but could not see anything about handling mouse scroll there :(

Then I have digged deeper through the [Ursina Engine API](https://www.ursinaengine.org/api_reference.html#mouse) reference... but neither there seems to be anything related.

Finally, I have also asked **ChatGPT** for any advice on how to approach this... but the AI seems to loop around the case with some propositions but none of those was even close to valid (I would not think it is worth to mention them, as those are full of (missing) `AttributeError`'s :p

---

ps: The game is not intended to be played without the wheel equipped mouse. It is intended to be played without the keyboard.

Comment: Have you checked `Keys.scroll_up = 'scroll up'`and `Keys.scroll_down = 'scroll down'`? They might be triggered.

Comment: The Ursina `FirstPersonController` has the WASD controls hard-coded. You can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67669320/9731347) about this issue.

Comment: @SanguineL - Yep... WASD is hard-codded there... but I can always override the `update(...)` method. The focus in this question is more on getting the mouse scroll distance than on how to use this to move the controller :P

Comment: @RogerLindsjö - how shall I use those?

Comment: @RogerLindsjö - I have tried to archive this by `ursina.input_handler.rebind('scroll up', 'w')` and `ursina.input_handler.rebind('scroll down', 's')`... and result is a bit weird 
I can start moving by scrolling forward but the movement does not stop when I stop scrolling. It can be stopped by scrolling backwards. And after this the movement is frozen... until either 'w' or 's' key got pressed (specifically, until one of those buttons is lifted up).

Comment: This is an example found (I have not tried it). https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/blob/master/ursina/scripts/scrollable.py